# How do I prove that a martingale has a constant expected value?

Tags: probability, martingales

I can´t prove that a martingale has constant expected value.
$$
\mathbf{E}[M_t]=\mathbf{E}[M_0]
$$

Thanks people.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should tell us what you tried to solve this problem. Also, have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math on this forum.

Comment: Hi! I tried this:

Comment: Hi! I tried this:

E[Mn+1]=E[E[Mn+1|Fn]]   correct? i think it is, because Mn+1 and Fn are independent right?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334996/martingale-expected-value) clear your doubts?

Answer (score 17):

It holds for any sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ that

$$\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) ] = \mathbb{E}(X).$$

Note that this does *not* require that $\mathcal{F}$ and $X$ are independent. Since a martingale satisfies

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = M_n,$$

we get

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n)] = \mathbb{E}(M_n)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(M_n) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)$.

Comment: Sorry for the pedantic question, but what exactly is a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$? It seems in some notes on Martindale, $\mathcal{F_n}$ is defined as $\{  X_n, X_n-1,\cdots X_1     \}$. Is it just some succinct way to write the large set of variables we're conditioning on?

Comment: @Iamanon $\mathcal{F}_n$ is typically the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.