# Simple Symmetric Random Walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, random-walk

A drunk man is at the 17th meter of a 100-meter-long bridge. He has 0.5 probability of moving forward or backward one meter each step. What is the probability that he will make it to the end of the bridge before the beginning ?

What is the expected number of steps he takes to reach either the beginning or the end of the bridge?

---

Solution:

Part 1). This is a martingale and that $E[S_n] = 0 = p_a * 83  + (1-p_a)*(-17) =0. \rightarrow p_a =0.17$.

Part 2). The martingale stops at $n$ is also a martingale. Let $N =$ stop time.

$E[S^2_N - N] = E[p_a *83^2 + (1-p_a )* 17^2]-E[N] =0. \rightarrow E[N] = 1441$.

**Confusion.**

**I don't understand how come you can treat $N$ as a constant. Shouldn't $N$ also be a random variable since you don't know the number of steps to get to the beginning or the end of the bridge? Also, how come $E[S^2_N - N] =0$?
Is it because that $E[S^2_N - N] = E[S^2_N]-E[N] = Var(S_N)-N$. And because $Var(S_n) = n$, thus, you have $E[S^2_N]-E[N] = N- N = 0$?**

Comment: Where are you treating $N$ as a constant?

Comment: @David, It's when you take the $E[N] = N$, aren't you treat it as a constant?

Comment: That is only in your attempt at the justification of the steps. I was wondering if it occurred in the actual solution.

Comment: No, I don't think the solution addressed that "N is a constant".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build intuition for this with Markov chains in matrices.

You can consider the smaller example of 6 "stepped" track:

$${\bf P} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}2&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&2\end{array}\right]$$

You can then by checking eigenvectors for ${\bf P}^T$ for $\lambda=1$. They are both linear functions $$\text{eigenvectors , }\lambda = 1\cases{[0\,1\,2\,3\,4\,5]^T\\ [5\,4\,3\,2\,1\,0]^T}$$

The second part of the question the estimated value is just the product $[1,0,0,0,0,1]{\bf T}{\bf v}$ where $\bf v$ is drunkard probability distribution ${\bf P}_m$ is P but removed endpoints $({\bf P_m})_{11} = 0, ({\bf P_m})_{66} = 0$

$${\bf T} = \sum_k (k-1){{\bf P}_m}^k$$

Comment: Just wondering. Is it true that the expectation of a martingale is always 0?

Comment: I am asking about expectation, not conditional expectation.

Comment: Why don't you build some intuition for it?

Comment: your answer is great, but unfortunately, I am not freshed with my linear algebra knoweldge.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a constant. It's a random variable. The fact is that $Sn^2 - n $ is also a martingale. So it's expected value is constant and equal to 0.

---

Comment: Just wondering. Is it true that the expectation of a martingale is always 0? I am asking expectation, not conditional expectation.

Comment: @wrek you may find this related Q&A helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197194/342780

Comment: An expectation of a Martingale isn't always 0. It depends on the first value S0.

Comment: @David, thanks for your reply. I am wondering $M_0$ of your link is the initial value of the martingale,right?

Comment: @user436884, in this case, the first value $S_0$ is the initial value of the martingale, right?

Comment: @wrek that's correct

Comment: @David, if that's the case, how do I know the initial value of $E[S_n^2 -N]$ of my part b?

Comment: @wrek what is the definition of $S_n$ in this problem?

Comment: $S_n$ is the simple random walk and that $S_n= X_1 + X_2 +X_3.....$ @David

Comment: And also, you assume the current position (the 17th meter ) to be 0, and the problem becomes a symmetric random walk that stops at either 83 or -17.

Comment: @wrek right, so $S_1^2 = X_1^2$. Since $X_1 \in \{-1,1\}$ we have that $X_1^2 = 1$. Hence, $S_1^2 = 1$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}(S_1^2 - 1) = 1 - 1 = 0$.