# Question on Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, self-learning, martingales

Show that The function $t \rightarrow E(M_t) $ is a constant function if M is martingale.

My attempt is

By the theorem, I know that if M is martingale, then $E[M_t]=E[M_0]$. Then I can say that this function is constant.

Is this explanation is true? I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Yes,  it is correct. Why do you doubt this argument?

Comment: Is $E(M_0)$ a constant value? I am not sure at this point. Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: When you say that $t \to EM_t$ is a constant function you mean that $EM_t$ does not depend on $t$. Of course $EM_t=EM_0$  and $EM_0$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: I see right now. Thanks a lot. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197194/36150)