# Question about the expectation of martingales

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let's say that I have a martingale $M_t$ with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Can I properly encounter the expectation of the martingale? What I mean is, is the following true?

$$\mathbb{E}[M_t] =^? \lim_{t \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathcal{F}_0] = M_0$$

If not how can I encounter $\mathbb{E}[M_t]$?

Comment: No limits need to be taken - just use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[M_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathscr{F}_s]] = \mathbb{E}[M_s] $ for $s < t$. Thus the expectation does not change with time, so $\mathbb{E}[M_t] = \mathbb{E}[M_0]$

Comment: See also [this (duplicate) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197194/36150)